# how to compare two range in two different files

Tags: perl, range

I have 2 files. 
1 file contains data as ranges (1st column) and values (2nd column):

```
1..10 1.5
5..15 4.2
```

The other file contains data as ranges:

```
3..14
19..23
```

I want to check whether individual elements of range in data 1 lie within the range of data 2, if yes then counting the number of such individual elements from range of data 1 whose having the value greater than 2.0 (2nd column in data 1). I am not getting how to put these range so that it could solve my problem.

Comment: You're asked an similar question 4 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904099/perl-query-to-check-whether-individual-elements-of-one-range-is-present-in-anoth and frankly, I did not understand the question even then nor now. (maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the expected output for the given input?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines1 = ( '1..10 1.5',
               '5..15 4.2',
             );
my @lines2 = ( '3..14',
               '19..23',
             );

my $sum = 0;
for my $line1 (@lines1) {
    my ($range1, $value) = split ' ', $line1;
    next if $value <= 2;

    my ($from1, $to1) = split /\.\./, $range1;
    for my $range2 (@lines2) {
        my ($from2, $to2) = split /\.\./, $range2;
        next if $to2 < $from1 or $to1 < $from2;

        my $from = $from1 < $from2 ? $from2 : $from1;
        my $to   = $to1   < $to2   ? $to1   : $to2;
        $sum += $value * ($to - $from + 1);
        warn "$value from $from to $to";
    }
}

print "$sum\n";
```

The result is [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)), so it must be right.